# Run time error resulting in unexpected values

Tags: python

The following problem is to build a car following model. Two parameters: Time step and reaction time are taken from the user. Acceleration rate is calculated so that at the end of the time-step (TS) the desired spacing will be reached.  Also, a reaction time of ∆t  is considered.  Before ∆t the current speed/acceleration of the follower will be maintained, then the new acceleration will take place for the remainder of the time step (TS), or for a duration TS- ∆t if TS> ∆t. If TS< ∆t, then the speed change will take place after ∆t (multiple TS).

Python code:

```
m=1
q=0
l=0
while q<32.5:
    distance.append(25-t_s*(float(v_follower[m-1])-float(v_leader[m-1])))
    if(distance[m]>5):
        if(t_s<r_t):
            if(l==r_t):
                v_follower.append(float(v_follower[m-1]+31.4*r_t))
                l=0
            else:
                v_follower.append(float(v_follower[m-1]))
                l+=t_s#write code for t_s>r_t
        else:
            v_follower.append(float(v_follower[m-1])+31.4*(t_s-r_t))
    else:
        if(t_s<r_t):
            if(l==r_t):
                v_follower.append(float(v_leader[m]))
                l=0
            else:
                v_follower.append(float(v_follower[m-1]))
                l+=t_s
        else:
            v_follower.append(float(v_leader[m]))
    m+=1
    q+=t_s
```

The expected result is a matrix with value above zero but tending towards zero at the end of the process. The actual result is all zeros.

Comment: Is the error that you get `NameError: name 'distance' is not defined`?

Comment: No. Just zeros!

Comment: Do you expect us to keep guessing what the run time error is?

Comment: The error is the output is a matrix full of zeros. I have mentioned that in my question and in the earlier comment.

Comment: A Runtime Error is a built-in Exception of Python. There should be an error printed out describing what went wrong. [RuntimeError](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html?highlight=runtime%20error#RuntimeError).